# Clearing a context in Core Data: reset vs deleting registered objects?

Tags: ios, core-data, reset, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I was looking for posts regarding to this, but I don't fully understand... What is the difference between:

```
[context reset];
```

and:

```
for (NSManagedObjectID *objId in objectIds) {
  [context deleteObject:[context objectWithID:objId]];
}
```

Or are they equivalent?

Thanks

Comment: Well, for one, reset affects EVERYTHING while deleteObject allows you do delete one SINGLE object.

Comment: @LordZsolt but assuming you're looping all the context's registered objects... is it the same?

Comment: Test something: Add 10 object to core data and save them. After that, modify the code to call reset (after the objects were saved to the persistent store). Now see if you fetch all the objects, do you still have them or they were deleted. I know that `deleteObject:` also removes the objects from the persistent store, however I don't know if reset does that or only drops the objects which are in the NSManagedObjectContext. Sorry that I don't write it myself, however I don't have an application with CoreData ready at the moment.

Comment: @LordZsolt I made a test with the `deleteObject:` method and it looks like it still is in the persistent store...

Comment: You have to call context.save() after context.delete(object) to reflect the deletion in the persistent store.

Answer (score 37):

Using `reset` puts the managed object context back to the state it was in when you first created it-- before you had performed any fetches, created any new objects, etc. If you have any managed objects in memory that were fetched from this context, they're now unusable. Using `reset` **does not affect the persistent store file**. All instances still exist afterward, they're just not in memory. They can be fetched again.

Using `deleteObject` removes the object from the persistent store. It does not exist any more. It can't be fetched anymore because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. I'm making some tests and I don't know why, after calling `deleteObject:` for all the registered objects in the context, I still have them in the persistent store and `context.registeredObjects.count` still is > 0. If I call `[context reset]`, then `context.registeredObjects.count` is 0 as I expected... why could this being happening?

Comment: Did you save changes?

Comment: @AppsDev you need to call save on the context to get rid of them.