# Core data delete vs reset

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

If I create a core data object, then decide to discard the changes instead of saving it, how should I achieve that? As far as I know, both of the following methods work:

// 1.

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let object = CoreDataObject(context: managedObjectContext)
...
managedObjectContext.reset()
```

// 2.

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let object = CoreDataObject(context: managedObjectContext)
...
managedObjectContext.delete(object)
```

Which one should I choose?

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32210346/4468859

Comment: According to Apple Docs, `reset()` is to return the context to its base state. "All the receiver's managed objects are “forgotten.” If you use this method, you should ensure that you also discard references to any managed objects fetched using the receiver, since they will be invalid afterwards."

Comment: What do you want actually ?  delete  specific data or delete every data ?

Comment: @Lawliet yeah using `reset()` does cause me some troubles as the manage object context is being used elsewhere.

Comment: @Roy I want to cancel creating one specific data, which is not stored in the context yet.

Comment: If you have not committed the changes, I will recommend `rollback` as it "removes everything from the undo stack, discards all insertions and deletions, and restores updated objects to their last committed values".

Answer (score 2):

I got some information from Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506847-delete):

> delete(_:)
>
> Specifies an object that should be removed from its persistent store when changes are committed.
>
> When changes are committed, object will be removed from the uniquing tables. If object has not yet been saved to a persistent store, it is simply removed from the receiver.

And so far using the `delete` method has caused no bug, comparing to unexpected crashes of `reset`.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to discard changes you should use reset or rollback.
If you wanted to delete from the persistent store (records that has been saved and persisted) you had to use delete.
For instance, a record is existed in core data. you fetch it and delete it.
but you have fetched some records but you want to discard this fetching you should use reset
**reset**:  It give you a clean NSManagedObjectContext with no objects in it.
**rollback**: It discards unsaved changes.
from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506942-rollback :

> Removes everything from the undo stack, discards all insertions and
>   deletions, and restores updated objects to their last committed
>   values.

Comment: Do you have some reference?

Comment: @BrightFuture look at this:  stackoverflow.com/a/32210346/4468859 but I will search for a better reference too.

Comment: Great answer! But plz note that I haven't saved yet, so `rollback` actually doesn't do anything, but it's great to know :)